# Resources for comparing mutual fund and ETF historical performance?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, etf

What are good magazines/publications/newspapers/websites to follow for someone wishing to compare historical performances of index funds, ETFs, managed funds etc?

Do I start with my bank's web site and compare performance of its various products? (TD Canada Trust)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with [Globefund](http://www.globefund.com) and [Morningstar](http://www.morningstar.ca). At Globefund, you can compare any mutual fund against a plethora of benchmarks. Not sure if you can compare between individual funds.